# Unable to assign a Foreign Key in DJango

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am trying to save data into a mysql database using 2 tables main and public, but am unable to store data into the public table.

ERROR: `ValueError: Cannot assign "4": "public.unq_id" must be a "main" instance.`

Models.py:

```
class main(models.Model):
    unq_id     = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    email      = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    password   = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    last_name  = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    dob        = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    phone      = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    status     = models.CharField(max_length = 12, default = 'active')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.unq_id

    def verify_password(self, raw_password):
        return pbkdf2_sha256.verify(raw_password, self.password)    


class public(models.Model):                                       
    unq_id          = models.OneToOneField(main, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key = True)  
    lang            = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    expert          = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    country         = models.CharField(max_length=80, default = "None")
```

Views.py:

```
Email1=request.POST['Email']
a = main.objects.filter(email = Email1).exists()
if a is True:
   error = "Email taken"
   return render(request, 'Main/registration.html',{'error':error})
password1=request.POST['password']
password = pbkdf2_sha256.encrypt(password1,rounds=12000,salt_size=32)
Fname=request.POST['Fname']
Lname=request.POST['Lname']
DOB=request.POST['dob2']
lang= request.POST['lang']
phone=request.POST['phone']
c = main.objects.filter(phone = phone).exists()
if c is True:
   error = "phone number taken"
   return render(request, 'Main/registration.html',{'error3':error})
country=request.POST['country']
r = countrycode.objects.filter(country = country).exists()
if r is True:
   s = countrycode.objects.get(country = country)
   country = s.code                         
main2=main(email=Email1,password=password,first_name=Fname,last_name=Lname,dob=DOB,phone=phone) 
main2.save()
mainobj= main.objects.get(email = Email1)   
    
public2=public(lang=lang,expert="false",country=country,unq_id=mainobj.unq_id)
public2.save()
```

When I look in my database, the mainobj gets stored but the public object doesn't get saved; despite having the same "unq_id"

Please do help , thank you

Comment: about foreign keys  read  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: Your ForeignKey/OneToOneField should preferably be named `unq`, not `unq_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that when you instantiate the public object you are trying to pass a "4" string / int, as an unq_id parameter when in fact you defined a OneToOne relation that is at the instance level relationship, so your public object in the unq_id attribute expects an object / instance of main.

Example:

```
main_test = main(email='test@test.com', password='test', ...)
public_test = public(unq_id=main_test,...)
```

In the Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) you can find all the aspects about this type of relationship, such as its restrictions or how the objects are retrieved when a query is made to the DB.